# Difference in pronunciation between 'warship' and 'worship'?

Tags: pronunciation, differences

I came across these words together in a text, and I was wondering whether they are pronounced the same way. 'War' is actually pronounced as 'wor', so I'm not entirely sure.

When I pronounce them, I do not hear a difference, but I'm not a native English speaker. Could anyone perhaps shed some light on whether the two words are pronounced differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sitting here saying the two words to myself and marveling that I never noticed that similarity in pronunciation before. :)

The difference is all in the "or."

In *worship*, the "or" is pronounced more as "ur" by most Americans. We say it as "wurship."

*Warship* is pronounced more the way it looks: "wawrship," with the mouth opening a bit wider on the "a."

Accent is on the first syllable in both words.

Comment: As Brian’s answer points out, this is slightly inaccurate about the British pronunciation — we too pronounce the ‘wor-’ of ‘worship’ to approximately rhyme with ‘fur’, ‘her’, etc.  Otherwise, completely agreed…

Comment: @PLL Deleted. I shouldn't have commented on British pronunciation. (It sounds different to my ear.)

Comment: This doesn't work in St. Louis, where they pronounce *pork* as "park" and *Highway 40* as "Highway Farty" ... So there would be no difference between *worship* and *warship* to them.

Comment: The variations among American dialects are so interesting. In east Texas, a lot of people pronounce "horse" so that it rhymes with "farce." They're quite selective with this and do it with only a handful of *or* words. IIRC, *forty* is one of them.

Answer (score 6):

I'd more or less agree with the above answer, apart from the part about the difference between English and American pronunciations.

Dictionary.com has the two pronounced as /ˈwɔrˌʃɪp/ [wawr-ship] for *warship*, and /ˈwɜrʃɪp/ [wur-ship] for *worship*. These are about how I'd expect them to sound as a British English speaker.

Merriam-Webster [suggests](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/worship) \'wər-shəp\ or \'wòr-shəp\ for *worship*. I'm not quite sure about either of those.

Comment: I find all of these answers very strange. For me, the sole difference is that *worship* is stressed only on the first syllable while *warship* has both stressed, just as though it were written *war ship*. Of course, I realise now that most accents differentiate them by pronunciation as well, and I'd naturally pronounce them differently if I were affecting another accent.

Comment: For me (AmE), the two differences. Inclassical poetic meter, 'warship' is a spondee (long-long) and 'worship' is a trochee (long-short). And without going into phonetics, the first syllables differe for me mostly as the vowel indicates.

Comment: Out of curiosity I looked up the pronunciations on thefreedictionary, and surprisingly the same sound has been put behind those words - please have a look at: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/warship and http://www.thefreedictionary.com/worship.

Answer (score 3):

The 'a' in Warship is like the 'a' in Law. It is a sound that is hard for a non English speaker to pronounce, try making 'law' and 'low' sound different, they should sound very different and this is part of the same issue.

The 'or' in Worship is like 'err' in "to err on the side of caution", or the mechanical sound that is associated with spinning, 'whirr', as in "The machine whirred past".

Comment: Er ... many of us Americans pronounce *err* as a homonym of *air* (although both pronunciations are correct, according to American dictionaries). So if *err* and *whirr* don't rhyme for you, it should be the same as *whirr*.

Comment: But if "whirr" and "fur" don't rhyme for you, it should be the same as "fur."

Answer (score 2):

Warship : wôrˌSHip ( more like Wor-Ship )

Worship: wərSHəp ( more like Wer-Ship )

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure, when I was a kid in Toronto, that we pronounced the word worship like "warship", as in, a ship of war.  I'm not sure I have any way to prove that.

Answer (score 1):

## Sounds like....

The **first** syllable of *worship* is pronounced the same way that the
word *were* is pronounced.  In contrast, the first syllable of *warship* is
pronounced the same way that the word *wore* is pronounced.  Those two
sound-alike words — *were, wore* — are unlikely to be pronounced the same
as each other in most accents, or maybe in any.

The **second** syllable of *worship* is pronounced the same way the second
syllable of the word *bishop* is pronounced.  In other words, it’s a very short,
unstressed syllable with a fully reduced neutral vowel, the one we call
schwa.  In contrast, the second syllable of *warship* is pronounced almost
as though it were the full word *ship*. It’s a separate morpheme in
a compound word that retains its original character, and it is not reduced.

## Looks like....

Precisely how you represent these two words phonetically very much depends
on which particular accent we’re talking about. The respective variants can
sound quite different from how each other sounds, and their corresponding
phonetic representations can often look even more unalike than the sounds.

All that variation aside, one reasonably simple representation that works
for rhotic speakers with monophthong vowels before rhotics would be to use
/ˈwəɹʃəp/ for *worship* and to use /ˈwoɹˌʃɪp/ for *warship*. Notice how the
second of those has a bit of secondary stress in its second syllable that
the first one lacks.

You should also be aware that most North American speakers, especially rhotic ones,
neutralize the lax–tense (or open–close) phonemic distinction (/ɔ‑o/, /ɛ‑e/) before
rhotics, perceiving each to always be the close variant in that position.
That makes *wore* have the same tense /o/ vowel as *woe* has for them, not
the lax /ɔ/ vowel they have in the word *wall*.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot hear a difference between the two at all. If I heard someone say either word out of context, I would have no idea which one they meant. (And for what it's worth, detecting audible differences comprises much of my life).

On the other hand, I agree with @Kelly C Hess -- despite their similarity, I am pretty sure I have never confused them. Fortunately there are probably very few cases when it would be ambiguous in context.